# Contact Form 7 file attachments not attaching to email

Tags: wordpress, email, email-attachments, contact-form-7

Apologies if this has been answered before but sadly, I read through multiple similar posts and none of the solutions applied to my situation.

As stated in the title, my form works correctly in sending me emails but doesn't include the file attachments. Below is the code from my form -

> Your Name*
> [text* your-name]
>
> Your Email*
> [email* your-email]
>
> Upload Photo [file your-file limit:25mb
> filetypes:pdf|doc|jpg|jpeg|png]
>
> [submit "Send"]

Then in the Mail tab, I've added [your-file]

Any help in troubleshooting this would be great. I contacted my Host (Siteground) who say they can't help and that it can't in any be them causing this through spam filter or any other way...

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: In the contact form, in the mail tab, did you add [your-file] in the "File Attachments" section?

Comment: Yes I have, this seems to be the solution for most having this problem but not for me

Comment: What is the maximum attachment size that they let you use with your host